# Argumentos de Shell a SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, shell-script

estoy haciendo un proyecto con `Shell Script` y `SpringBoot` generando un .jar, el jar ya lo tengo corriendo sin problema, el detalle es el envío de los parámetros, en el cual estoy enviando desde shell hacia Spring, mi código en Shell es:

```
java -jar ruta/target/MyApp.jar Alex 19
```

El primer parámetro (Alex) Es un nombre y el segundo (19) es la edad

En Spring tengo:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApp implements CommandLineRunner {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        //Aquí intento recibir los parámetros
        reporte.detalleReporte(args[0], args[1]);
    }
}
```

reporte.DetalleReporte es un método que ya funciona con datos en duro (Por eso no pongo el @Autowired en el ejemplo) Ahora el detalle son los parámetros que vienen desde Shell Script.

Al ejecutar me manda el error:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Espero alguien pueda asesorarme. ¡Agradezco su tiempo!
¡Saludos!

Comment: Te aseguraste de que los parámetros lleguen al `main()`, porque en lo que muestras no hay nada incorrecto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias por sus respuestas, ya lo he resuelto:
Resulta que en el Bash había que ponerle el nombre del valor por ejemplo:

```
#!/bin/bash
nombre = $1
edad = $2

java -jar ruta/target/MyApp.jar $nombre $edad
```

Al ejecutar el archivo bash en la terminal:

```
[usuario@pc3 bash]$ ./archivoBash Alex 19
```

Llegan al main.
¡saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Obtienes el error:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

ya que en realidad no estas recibiendo ningùn valor en `main(String[] args)`.

Te sugiero validar aquì:

```
@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    //Aquí intento recibir los parámetros
   
 if(args.length > 0){
    reporte.detalleReporte(args[0], args[1]);         
 }else{
     System.out.println("No se reciben valores!");
 }

}
```

La forma como lo realizas deberìa funcionar, pero es importante asegures que la ruta del `.jar` sea correcta y usa comilla doble para los valores ya que el array que se recibe es de valores tipo `String`:

```
java -jar ruta/target/MyApp.jar "Alex" "19"
```

Comment: No es necesario agregar las comillas para que Java convierta los parámetros a `String`. Agregarlas solo es necesario si alguno de estos parámetros contiene espacios en blanco u otros caracteres que requieran ser escapados para que el parámetro se interprete correctamente.